# What is the purpose of std::add_lvalue_reference and std::add_rvalue_reference?

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of `std::add_lvalue_reference` and `std::add_rvalue_reference`?

It seems that using `T &`/`T &&` does the same, as this successfully compiles:

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
    { using T = int;    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, T &>); };
    { using T = int &;  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, T &>); };
    { using T = int &&; static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, T &>); };

    { using T = int;    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>, T &&>); };
    { using T = int &;  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>, T &&>); };
    { using T = int &&; static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>, T &&>); };
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void&` is ill-formed.  `std::add_lvalue_reference<void>` is `void`.

In general, `add_lvalue_reference` does not add reference to types if it is not possible.  Per [[meta.trans.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.trans.ref#lib:add_lvalue_reference):

> ```
> template <class T>
> struct add_­lvalue_­reference;
> ```
>
> If T names a referenceable type then the member typedef `type` names
>   `T&`; otherwise, `type` names `T`. [ *Note:* This rule reflects the
>   semantics of reference collapsing ([dcl.ref]). — *end note* ]

What is a referenceable type?  Per [[defns.referenceable]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.referenceable), a referenceable type is

> an object type, a function type that does not have cv-qualifiers or a
>   ref-qualifier, or a reference type [ *Note:* The term describes a type
>   to which a reference can be created, including reference types.
>   — *end note* ]

Answer (score 4):

They're not the same in all cases. The effects of [`std::add_lvalue_reference`, `std::add_rvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) are,

> 1) If T is an object type or a function type that has no cv- or ref-
>   qualifier, provides a member typedef type which is T&. If T is an
>   rvalue reference to some type U, then type is U&. Otherwise, type is
>   T.
>
> 2) If T is an object type or a function type that has no cv- or ref-
>   qualifier, provides a member typedef type which is T&&, otherwise type
>   is T.

e.g. the result would be defferent for funciton type has cv- or ref-qualifier. The following code fails,

```
{ using T = void() const;    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, T &>); };
```

The result of `std::add_lvalue_reference` is just `T` here.

```
{ using T = void() const;    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>, T>); };
```